# Strange Intermittent Background Sound in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio

Ok, this is very strange.   Recently, i noticed that every 10-15 seconds, there would be this faint, annoying  duh-dum sound coming out of my speakers. (hard to describe. sounds somewhat like the sound windows makes when you unplug a USB device, but not as pronounced and much quieter).

I closed every app and ended as many processes as I could, but the sound persists.

I look at the volume mixer and sure enough, when the sound occurs, there is a little spike in the level under "System Sounds".

I haven't installed any hardware or software in the last several weeks.

This started recently - completely out of the blue.  Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, same problem here.  I did fix it by clicking the *Volume Control » Mixer » System Sounds icon* to bring up the system sounds selection window.

Scroll down and look for "device failed to connect". Choose that. You will notice it's the same sound that's looping.

All I did was use the drop down menu and selected *None*. That stopped the repeating sound for me, for now. It may not be a fix but it works!

Comment: actually I found out later that my external hard drive was acting up, so it was a device causing the beep.  Unplugged, rebooted, okay now.

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed anything recently? Hardware or software?

What I would advise you do is open up Device Manager and just watch, if this is hardware, it should refresh and you should be able to tell what device was added or removed.

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem, it was because microphone had "listen to this device". And there was no mic in, so i guess it started to pick radio waves

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and solution for now:

> Look for "device failed to connect", choose that. (You will notice its the same sound that's looping) ... It may not be a fix but it works!

I did the same thing as above and everything is okay, **BUT** "device failed to connect" had its cause: I have a WD Passport (external drive), which was disconnected after a while.

Answer (score 1):

Test all of you USB connections. If there is anything loose it seems that it can make your computer play that noise, even if everything is functioning properly. I had a problem with a Western Digital external hard drive causing the same noise to occur on my computer (I have also read others with the same problem from these hard drives). Unplugging that  fixed the noise right away.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem, but it doesn't happen every 10-15 seconds. I found my solution here:  https://superuser.com/questions/333880/what-is-the-source-of-this-funny-noise-in-windows/333958#333958

This is due to dog avatar in the Windows Search Results window. If you click on him, he scratches himself.  But if you ignore him (apparently) he occasionally scratches himself, which causes an intermittent noise.

Also: http://www.audiomastersforum.net/amforum/index.php/topic,5527.0/wap2.html

Comment: I guess you meant: [What is the source of this funny noise in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/333880/what-is-the-source-of-this-funny-noise-in-windows/333958#333958)

Comment: @slhck sorry, Yes. I found that SU question too, after posting my answer here. Should have come back and linked to it.  Thanks

Comment: @slhck, edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the be-boop was due to a bluetooth adapter (ASUS PCE-AC55BT) that I had installed but disabled due to another issue.  Win7 wants to keep trying to install a driver for it, hence the sounds.  Once I re-installed the driver and BT was connected, the sound stopped.

Answer (score 0):

In my case a  USB flash drive was causing it.
Unplugged it then re-installed it.  That seems to have been the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the 'duh dum' sound at startup:

If you wish, you can check this link where i am copying from:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/in-the-device-manger-on-portable-devices-fghi-i/7656d7d3-4cb1-4a81-80b4-51219b4cc28a?tm=1362343286441#_self

Easy one-click solution told by Maincoon11:

All this uninstalling /reinstalling check disk, etc , was absolutely unnecessary!
 Windows 7 has a search program and files toolbar (located on  the left bottom corner) after you press start button on windows( just below) All Files. If you go to start and type on search toolbar Devices, Windows gives you choices, amongst them was one command " Find and Fix Problems with Devices". When you click on it, Windows searches for problems. it did find E F,G:\,H:\errors, one by one it fixed it.  That's all!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same and tried disconnecting my devices one by one until the noise stopped. It was a printer I had recently re-downloaded a driver for. I then reconnected the device and switched it on. This triggered Windows 7 to install the driver and now all is silence.

Answer (score 0):

Found By Changing windows Sound tab, Windows Explorer, Start Navigation sounds: to none. This got rid of my unknown noise every couple of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I was hearing a really sharp double beep which was really annoying doing Zoom.

Using @BGs answer, I was able to turn off the System Sounds and narrow it down.

In my case it turned out to be Windows Gadgets.  In particular the `Network Meter`.  It had an alert for lost connection.

Answer (score -1):

I experience the duh dun sound after installing a BIOS Update.

To make that sound or all sounds go away, here is what you do:

1. From main screen in Windows, click on the Speaker on the bottom right side of the screen
2. Click Mixer
3. Click System Sounds
4. Under Sound Scheme, select NO SOUNDS and Apply.
5. You are done. Close all boxes.