# Can I identify what process plays random beeps in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strange Intermittent Background Sound in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/80981/strange-intermittent-background-sound-in-windows-7)
>   [What process is making that sound?](https://superuser.com/questions/138002/what-process-is-making-that-sound)

I am have a random (seems random) beeping sound from my speaker in my Windows 7 machine

Even if I have no program opened I have the sound

Is there a way to know what process is emitting the sound?
Like a history of all sound files used?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What process is making that sound?](http://superuser.com/questions/138002/what-process-is-making-that-sound) also [Strange Intermittent Background Sound in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/80981/strange-intermittent-background-sound-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 2):

If this happens frequent enough, you could right click the audio icon in the notification area and click on **Open Volume Mixer**; there you can see which application is currently playing audio. There is no history available for this, and it is really impractical to  figure out the sound file given that it might not have an obvious extension. [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) allows you to search for open handles, just hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and search for common extensions like `.wav` and `.mp3` and so on...

Comment: Open Volume Mixer might do it for him.. but regarding pexp.. if the file is played only for a moment, would pexp pick it up?

Comment: @barlop: Some applications keep a file handle open, others just load it into memory and close the handle. It's worth trying and the best bet, given that you can't record the audio and search for it in memory. I'm wondering whether the Windows Performance Toolkit is able to track this down, I have no experience with audio in it though...

Comment: haven't tried it.. but process monitor can and i'd think moreso than process explorer. There aren't too many common audio file types. mp3 wav au wma.

Comment: @barlop: I doubt if Process Monitor will have any effect, in that case the file would have to be opened at the moment the sound would play. A lot of applications just load the audio in advance...

Comment: good point, but probably a lot just open it and close it when they want to play it. In the case of yahoo messenger I knew yahoo messenger was making a sound but didn't know with what file, I caught it with process monitor (so I suppose it just opened it played it and closed it whenever it wanted to  play it). process monitor didn't work so well for catching the dog scratching windows xp search sound though(but it's possible I wasn't searching it right).

Answer (score 0):

Some hard drives seem to be able to emit a "beep" sound. If your beep is accompanied with a click, it's probably the hard drive. See e.g. http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19365865.aspx

Comment: SPEAKER  see he wrote SPEAKER